# Why is a mac typically slow/laggy after upgrading the OS?

Tags: macos, software-update, upgrade, performance

I recently updated macOS to a new major version (Big Sur). I've read many claims that a newly upgraded macOS installation may be slow/laggy for 1–7 days because it needs to perform "various maintenance routines" and a user should wait through this period, after which time their computer will become efficient and stable again.

I'm looking for clarification around the popular and folkloric notions of *what macOS needs to do after an OS upgrade that make it inherently slow/laggy **for a limited time***.

I see two categories of info, but I'm mainly interested in the first:

1. Inherent reasons the OS **needs** to be slow *(e.g. Siri/Spotlight reindexing)*
2. Universally common reasons for slowness *(e.g. iCloud synchronization issues or native Mac apps performing background updates)*

Comment: Who made those "claims"? Is this beer research or factual and verified fact?

Comment: Yes, it is verified fact that people have made these claims. https://osxdaily.com/2021/01/20/macos-big-sur-slow-speed-tips-fix/

Comment: That's a story on how to resolve generic issues with speed.  It contains only generalized observations so we need to be careful claiming those are 'verified facts'.

Comment: I never claimed the statements in that article were verified facts. I stated that the claims themselves were verified to have been made. If you want to participate, please read what I've stated carefully and don't make your own inferences outside of what I've stated. Also, if you were to actually read that article, you can see that it mentions the exact topic I'm asking about as item #1. I even quoted the article when I cited "various maintenance routines". Also, I urge you to consider why I would be asking a question about something I knew to be a "verified fact".

Answer (score 1):

Right after an upgrade, system applications and services might need to do background work, which could mean that the user experiences the system as "slower than usual".

As you mention in your question, this can include Spotlight reindexing, but could also be for example Photos rescanning photos to create metadata.

There's no need to have to believe in any "folklore" though. You can easily determine whether or not your computer, after an upgrade, is engaged in such activities. Simply start Activity Monitor and look at the CPU time taken up by such services.

As you mention, these types of background operations completely within a fairly limited amount of time - and then you'll experience the performance level that you'll probably become accustomed to after a while. It might be the exact same performance level you saw right after upgrading, and it might be better. It's usually a quite individual experience.